# @EJB and @Inject both causing NPE in Glassfish 3.1.2 and Java 6

Tags: glassfish-3, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm deploying a Maven WebApp created with NetBeans 3.1.2 on Mac using lastest JDK 6 and Glassfish 3.1.2

It contains a basic JAX-RS service. I tried inject both a SLSB (with @EJB) and a CDI managed bean (@Inject) into it. In both cases I hit NPE.

> SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.mycompany.common.jee6.glassfish3.webapp.GenericResource.getXml(GenericResource.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

To save on ink the project is uploaded here

https://bitbucket.org/DessieK/jee6-cdi-webapp/src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your JAX-RS service a stateless session bean:

```
@Path("generic")
@Stateless // <- It's an EJB
public class GenericResource {
    @EJB
    NewSessionBean nsb;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getXml() {
        nsb.helloWorld();
        return "<hello>World</hello>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Why is it that the container cannot inject into a JAX-RS service without this?

Comment: @DarVar: it's a workaround. JAX-RS is not integrated with CDI and EJB so no injection is possible. Making the class an EJB allow you to use injection. I'm not sure but it seems that JAX-RS 2.0 (JavaEE 7 - actually only Glassfish 4) solve the problem.